# How to find the entry point of a specific thread in Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out how to find the entry point of a specific **thread** in Windows. I know of various ways to get the entry point of a *process*, but not of a **thread**. I've looked at a few different structures/methods (`TIB`, `PEB`, and `GetThreadContext`) that might be able to access it, but it doesn't seem that they do. I've also checked out the `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO` info structure -- which has access to the start routine -- but it seems that the only way to populate it is by actively debugging the process and calling `WaitForDebugEvent`. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you look in the source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use NtQueryInformationThread with ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684283%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd try:

- putting a breakpoint on CreateThread
- examining exe file in IDA Pro *(I'm pretty sure there was a free version of it)*